# Ruby on Rails & Mongomapper : wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I am new to ruby on rails.I am trying to search brokers,whose name contains "Jam" but its giving me error of "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". Following is my code:

```
@brokers = Broker.where("firstName = ?", "Jam")
```

Why am i getting wrong number of arguments error?

Comment: `@brokers = Broker.where(firstName:  "Jam")`

Comment: its giving same error.

Comment: it should hash like key value firstname is key and value is jam

Comment: Your rails version? Copy and paste actual error trace in your post

Comment: Its ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Preet, I was looking for rails version not ruby's actually

Comment: Did you remove activerecord components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using MongoMapper, you may need to use `all`. You can try following query:

```
@brokers = Broker.all(firstName: "Jam")
```

OR

```
@brokers = Broker.where(firstName: "Jam").all
```

Source: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html

**Update:**

To use `like` behavior, you can use regexp such as:

```
@brokers = Broker.all(firstName: /Jam/)
```

Comment: How can i use it with like? I want to fetch all the records containing 'Jam' in firstName.

Answer (score 3):

```
@brokers = Broker.where(firstName: "Jam")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose it in array:

```
@brokers = Broker.where(["brokers.firstName = ?", "Jam"])
```

That being said, we need to know your rails version (and ruby version). However if you are not interested in using `LIKE`, you can just do

```
@brokers = Broker.where(firstName: "Jam")
```

ActiveRecord has some sql-builder built within (and supports [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) if you want to), which allows you to write `Brokers.where(hash_key: value)` and it will convert it to `SELECT * FROM brokers WHERE hash_key = value`, so you can write simple queries in a faster way.

The version you posted is not working because `where` accepts a single string, an array or an hashmap, [doesn't accept multiple params](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where).

**Update 1 (after discovering you are using mongomapper):**

After discovering that you are using [mongomapper](https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper), which is **very different** from a default Rails installation (*be careful* if you are new, lot of stuff won't apply to you, Rails by default uses [activerecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord)), I believe you have to add `all` at the end of your call, like they do in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110385/query-is-not-executing-in-rails-app-using-mongomapper). So something like:

```
@brokers = Broker.where(firstName: "Jam").all
```

Also notice that **this way of querying won't work with mongomapper:** (at least by checking documentation)

```
@brokers = Broker.where(["brokers.firstName = ?", "Jam"])
```

So you are forced to use the one with `where(firstName: "Jam")`

**Update 2 (how to perform query similar to SQL LIKE):**

If you want to let code behave in a similar fashion like SQL `LIKE`, as you are requesting in comments, you are able to use regexp, so something like:

```
@brokers = Broker.where(firstName: /.*Jam.*/)
```

Comment: Giving error : #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery firstName: "Jam", transformer: #<Proc:0xbd97d5c@/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.1/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>

Comment: So you are using mongodb, this is not standard rails installment, it's important to know rails version. And ruby is a bit outdated being 1.9.3

Comment: Also, what's the exception raised? This `#<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery firstName: "Jam", transformer: #<Proc:0xbd97d5c@/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.1/lib/mongo_mapper/p‌​lugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>` it's an object, not an error. Did you try run `to_a` on it and see if it's containing data?

Comment: Check my updated answer, adding `.all` at the end of the query should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine with 'all'. How can i use it with 'like' ? I want to fetch all the records which contain "Jam" in firstName.

Comment: Looks like you can use regexps in mongomapper, check the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6806845/312907 something like `where(firstName: /.*Jam.*/)` should work (can't test though, I'm not mongomapper user)